# Unable to locate an element when "show user agent shadow DOM" is enabled

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

[image]

As for the image, I need to capture an element which is under `show user agent shadow DOM`.

I tried using /`/*[@id="placeholder"]`, but as for the image, its Zero matches.
By looking at some other older post at this website I tried using

```
WebElement ele = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element);
```

for that also, I'm not getting the element.
So Is there any other way to capture the element below the `show user agent shadow DOM`.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript code you provided is almost accurate; however, some modification is needed to effectively capture an element within the Shadow DOM.

Firstly, obtain the JavaScript path of the intended element for locating using, copy jS path.

[image]

Subsequently, paste the path into the console and press Enter, ensuring the precise selection of the correct element .

[image]

Next, go ahead and use the provided JavaScript in your code. Simply paste the jS path into the specified JavaScript context.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement download = (WebElement) js.executeScript("return Paste the jS path after return");
```

If you intend to trigger a click event on the element, consider utilizing the following JavaScript code:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", download);
```